# SIG_ABRT on UITableViewCell delete

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to use the Apple provided "Edit" -> (-) -> "Delete" functionality to remove a row from my UITableView.

I have the button activated here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

The UITableViewCell created here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    PositionCell *cell = (PositionCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[PositionCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    FSExAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FSExAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Position *pos = [appDelegate.positions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell setPosition:pos];

    // Configure the cell.

    return cell;
}
```

And then just the Apple provided code:

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
```

When I perform the delete action, I get stuck at:

```
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

with "Thread 1: Program recieved signal 'SIGABRT'".

I've been trawling the questions here but can't seem to find anything for this issue. Can anyone help?

DJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're leaving out:

```
[mutableArrayAsDataSource removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

That should probably happen before the deleteRowsAtIndexPaths call.

Answer (score 0):

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

please change this to below

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[urArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```